# regular expression to remove all other words except the words between special characters in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex-replace

I am trying to create a regex in Notepad++ to remove words except those enclosed between special characters. I am using this regex `\<.*?\>` which removes the words along with text.

Eg:
Sample text

```
random text <ABCD> random text
random text <QWERT> random text
random text <XYZ> random text
```

Output

```
random text random text
random text random text
random text random text
```

I just want the opposite of the above regex

Eg:
Sample text

```
random text <ABCD> random text
random text <QWERT> random text
random text <XYZ> random text
```

Output

```
<ABCD>
<QWERT>
<XYZ>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<.+?>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.+?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<.+?>       # matches the string to be kept
(*SKIP)     # skip this match
(*FAIL)     # considere it failed
  |           # OR
.+?         # match any character but newline
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
(?m).+?(<.*?>|$)
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

where:

- `(?m)` is a flag activating the [multiline mode](https://javascript.info/regexp-multiline-mode)
- `.+?` searches for one or more characters (but as less as possible)
- `(<.*?>|$)` matches the desired pattern or the end of the line

#### Screenshots

Before:
[image: Screenshot before]

After:
[image: Screenshot after]